# .htaccess Redirect 301 any subdirectory to a different url from main path

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm not regex expert and I'm failing on what it looks like a simple task:

I need to 301 redirect urls like this:

```
/en/example/ www.example.com/hello-world/

/en/example/ANYTHING www.example.com/foobar/
```

the only way I can think of it is like that

```
/en/example/(.+) www.example.com/foobar/
```

but this is overriding the other rule and I'm not able to redirect "/en/example/" on a separate url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have 2 separate rules for this. First the specific one and then the general one.

```
RewriteRule ^en/example/?$ /hello-world/ [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^en/example/(.+?)/?$ /foobar/ [L,NC]
```

Comment: anubhava, as I'm at my first steps with regex, may I ask you why on the first rewrite rule you've put the question mark? I know the question mark follows optional matches, but that string must be there, is not optional!

Comment: Sure I can answer that. in the first rule I have put `?` in front of `/` to make it optional. Which means above rule will match both `/en/example/` and `/en/example`

Comment: Maybe I understand now: the question mark refers just to the single preceding character. If i want to make the whole part optional I do have to use round brackets, like this: ^(en/example/)?$ right?