# Redirect 301 old posts inside directory and subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to add some redirect 301 on my website.
I moved my website to WordPress from previous cms. The domain is still the same but a lot of links and pages don't exist anymore.

I would like to redirect lots of sub-directories and pages to the homepage or some directory.

In particular I am trying to redirect:

- domain.it/en/directory-one/subdirectory-one/...*(everything is inside this directory)* --> domain.it/en/new-page - **To a new page**
- domain.it/en/directory-one/subdirectory-two/...*(everything is inside this directory)* --> domain.it/en/new-page-two - **To another new page**

I've tried with this but no success:

```
RewriteRule ^/?en/directory/sub-directory-one/(.+)$ http://domain.it/en/new- [L,R=301]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Rule looks fine, can you show full .htaccess?

Comment: Sure @anubhava.

This is my htaccess. I have a WordPress installation in a subdirectory. 
I followed this [https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory]


`
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
`



I even tried this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412385/htaccess-redirect-301-any-subdirectory-to-a-different-url-from-main-path] but no success

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I've tried placing it before everything but it doesn't work.
I've also tried right after "RewriteEngine On" but no works. Right after "RewriteBase /" but no success...

Comment: this is my current htaccess:

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: Is there any other .htaccess in your system?